# Сохранение div блока

Tags: php, html

Имеется DIV блок, который наполняется контентом после загрузки страницы средствами JS. Задача в том чтобы содержимое по нажатию кнопки сохранялось в файле на сервере. 
К примеру

```
<div class="getcode">
Наполняемый контент, другие div блоки 
</div>
```

Как средствами php организовать сохранение внетренностей, именно куска кода который в этом блоке в файл, то бишь на сервере в определенную папочку кладутся .html файлы c содержимым этого блока.

Comment: Я бы сделал так : по нажатию на кнопку получаете element.innerhtml() и отправляете его ajax запросом на сервер, там сохраняете куда хотите.

Comment: @koks_rs можно  примере  этого div'а показать?, я новичок в JS и PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML файл

```
<div class="getcode">Наполняемый контент, другие div блоки</div>
<button>Получить и сохранить сожержимое</button>

<script>
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", sendSave, false);

    function sendSave() {
        var data = document.querySelector(".getcode").innerHTML;

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("data", data);

        var XHR = "onload" in new XMLHttpRequest() ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
        var xhr = new XHR();
        xhr.open('POST', 'save.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
                return;
            }
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
</script>
```

PHP файл save.php

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen(date('Ymdhis').'-data.html', 'w');

    echo (fwrite($fp, $_POST['data'])) ? "Сохранено" : "Не сохранено";

    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: по нажатию кнопки сохранить ничего не срабатывает

Comment: В консоли что пишет? Должен появиться файл в той же директории где лежат эти 2 файла. В консоли текст или сохранено или не сохранено.

Comment: если у меня html+JS в одном файле gethtml.php а пых в save.php то не работает, а если в одном файле в save.php то при загрузке страницы он автоматом сохраняет, консоль выдает в 1 и во 2 случае save.php:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null(…)(anonymous function) @ save.php:5
Navigated to http://dizelist18.ru/lk/admin/save/save.php

Comment: Расположите js после html - переместите script вниз

Comment: сохраняет, а возможно ли использовать эту технологию несколько раз? то бишь 3 div блока с разным наполнением но все класса=getcode сохранят в 1 файл контент

Comment: Конечно можно, нужно взять все содержимое всех div.getcode положить в массив, далее направить этот массив на сервер - там его обработать и записать в один файл.

Comment: А как это сделать если не секрет, я не свосем знаю как это запрограммировать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48835/discussion-between---and-).

Answer (score 0):

Сперва тебе нужно получить конент с помошью POST - GET запроса:

```
<div class="getcode">
<form method="post">
<textarea name="content">
Наполняемый контент, другие div блоки 
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить на html файл" name="otpravit"></input>
</form>
</div>
```

далее создаем файл с полученным контентом:

```
if (isset($_POST['otpravit']))
{
$content = $_POST['content'];
}
$newFileName = "getcode.html";
$newFileContent = $content;

if(file_put_contents($newFileName,$newFileContent)!=false){

}else{

}
```

Comment: возможно это сделать по нажатию кнопки?

Comment: Добавил html код там идет по нажатии кнопки конечно же.

Comment: Сейчас поправлю ответ.Чтобы можно было получить контент с тегами.